# Smarty user-defined built-in functions autoloading

Tags: php, smarty, built-in

In Smarty template when I write `{call "foo"}` I have to include template with "foo" implementation before calling function foo. Is it exists known way for autoloading such user-defined functions to prevent manual including templates with functions implementation in each file contains custom built-in function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. From my point of view, the most practical approach would be to move the definition of foo to higher level template.